# "TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable"

Tags: python-3.x

Why am i getting this error when trying to remove dupes from a list?

> "TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable"

trying to remove duplicate valuse from a list

```
numbers=[5,2,1,7,2,4]
numbers.sort()
i=0
for item in numbers:
    if i==len(numbers)-1:
    break
    elif item[i]==item[i+1]:
    numbers.remove(item)
i+=1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the problem is in your `for loop` it is not for removing duplicate numbers. i recommend that you must define a empty list in which you append elements one by one using loop and check if the element is already present in your list then don't append. here is the code:

```
numbers=[5,2,1,7,2,4]
numbers.sort()
sorted_num=[]
i=0
for i in range(0,len(numbers)-1):
    if numbers[i] in sorted_num:
        continue
    else:
        sorted_num.append(numbers[i])
        i+=1
print (sorted_num)
#     elif item[i]==item[i+1]:
#         numbers.remove(item)
# i+=1
```

i only edited your piece of code

Comment: interesting approach. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

use `set` see more [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets)

```
numbers=[5,2,1,7,2,4]   

list(set(numbers))      
[1, 2, 4, 5, 7]
```

Comment: My problem was from a homework and i don`t think i can use "set". But it is good to know this command exists. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use dictionary:

```
numbers=[5,2,1,7,2,4,5,5,1]
numbers=list(dict.fromkeys(numbers))
print(numbers)
```