# I'm getting 'int' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python

I'm new to python I'm trying to implement a code for my project at first my error code was object of type 'int' has no len() this was my code and added str to solve the issue

```py
xored_value = ord(Mblocks[i%len(Mblocks)]) ^ ord(Cblocks[i%len(Cblocks)])
```

Now I'm getting 'int' object is not subscriptable if in this line

```py
xored_value = ord(Mblocks[i%len(str(Mblocks))]) ^ ord(Cblocks[i%len(str(Cblocks))])
```

If I change it to

```py
xored_value = ord(Mblocks(i%len(str(Mblocks)))=)) ^ ord(Cblocks(i%len(str(Cblocks))))
```

I get `'str' object is not callable`.

Here's my full function :

```py
def xor_two_str(Mblocks,Cblocks):
    xored = []
    for i in range(max(len(str(Mblocks)), len(str(Cblocks)))):
        xored_value = ord(Mblocks[i%len(str(Mblocks))]) ^ ord(Cblocks[i%len(str(Cblocks))])
        xored.append(hex(xored_value)[2:])
    return ''.join(xored)
```

Any help please?

Comment: What are Mblocks and Cblocks?  Are they list of strings or string themselves?  Since it doesn't have a len property I'm assuming it's neither of these.  Can you provide an example of input for Mblocks and Cblocks?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61713384/typeerror-int-object-is-not-subscriptable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I am sure the Mblocks and Cblocks parameters you are passing are integers. Since it is being an integer, if you try to slice part of it you will get TypeError

```
> 100[1]
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

Lets do a piece by piece inspection.
Here in the first approach:

```
> xored_value = ord(Mblocks[i%len(Mblocks)]) ^ ord(Cblocks[i%len(Cblocks)])

> error1 = len(Mblocks)
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
```

since Mblocks is integer, integer doesn't have len function

In change 2,
you corrected the first error but:

```
> xored_value = ord(Mblocks[i%len(str(Mblocks))]) ^ ord(Cblocks[i%len(str(Cblocks))])

> error2 = Mblocks[i%len(str(Mblocks))]
> error2 = Mblocks[some_int]
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

In change 3:

```
xored_value = ord(Mblocks(i%len(str(Mblocks)))=)) ^ ord(Cblocks(i%len(str(Cblocks))))

> error3 = Mblocks(callingWithParameter)
```

Simply in python `something(withbraces)` is calling **something**. Same happened here

So the easiest solution is make Mbraces and Cbraces of  before you process anything down Like here is the solution:

```
def xor_two_str(Mblocks,Cblocks):
 Mblocks = str(Mblocks)
 Cblocks = str(Cblocks)
 xored = []
 for i in range(max(len(Mblocks), len(Cblocks))):
      xored_value = ord(Mblocks[i%len(Mblocks)]) ^ ord(Cblocks[i%len(Cblocks)])
      xored.append(hex(xored_value)[2:])
 return ''.join(xored)
```

Answer (score 1):

Python expects strings for the [`ord()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ord), and this:

`Mblocks[i%len(str(Mblocks))]`

is an attempt to access element with index `i%len(str(Mblocks))` from  `int` Mblocks, which Python does not allow.

As such, you could do a `str` conversion at the beginning of your function and work with the converted variables from that point onwards.

```
def xor_two_str(Mblocks,Cblocks):
    str_Mblocks=str(Mblocks)
    str_Cblocks=str(Cblocks)
    xored =[]
    for i in range(max(len(str_Mblocks), len(str_Cblocks))):
        xored_value = ord(str_Mblocks[i%len(str_Mblocks)]) ^ ord(str_Cblocks[i%len(str_Cblocks)])
        xored.append(hex(xored_value)[2:])
    return ''.join(xored)
```